# Jquery Focus selects the whole page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, clipboard

I am trying to implement a copy to clipboard function in my Ruby on Rails application. In my partial, I have this code:

```
<div class="share"/>
    <button class='my_clip_button clipboard' data-clipboard-text='<%= request.base_url.chomp('/') + trailer_path(trailer) %>'title='Click me to copy to clipboard.'>
      <%= image_tag('copy.png', :class=>"img-responsive") %>
    </button>
      <div class="reminder">
        <p>Copy link</p>
      </div>
      <input type="text" name="Element To Be Copied" class = "clipboardtext"
      id="inputContainingTextToBeCopied" value='<%= request.base_url.chomp('/') + trailer_path(trailer) %>'
      style="display:none; position: relative; left: -10000px;"/>
    </div>
```

In my javascript helper, I have:

```
$('.clipboard').click(function(){
  $(this).closest(".share").find(".clipboardtext").focus();
  document.execCommand('SelectAll');
  document.execCommand("Copy", false, null);
  copyDiv.style.display = 'none';

});
```

Going up the tree, shouldn't I go to the parent div, and then find the first element with the corresponding class? I am confused as to why the whole web page is selected. It's easier with an ID as I can simply use getElementById, but I'm not sure on how to go about this for classes/multiple elements. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
$(this).siblings(".clipboardtext").focus();
```

or:

```
$(this).parent(".share").find(".clipboardtext").focus();
```

Comment: Just tried both, and the whole page is still selected.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have malformed div tag:

```
<div class="share"/>
```

should be

```
<div class="share">
```

otherwise on testing it works.

Comment: Still copies the whole page :(.

Comment: You can't focus on an element that is hidden.  If you remove style="display:none;"  This will work

Comment: If i use document.queryselector('.clipboardtext') I get the right thing, but only for the first element of course.. weird